# Find the classname of a UI control

Tags: java, swing

I need a tool which tells the classname of the UI control on which my mouse pointer is. My GUI is in Swing. Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current location of the mouse pointer by doing:

```
Point location = MousePointer.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

Once you have the location, you can convert it to your parent containers coordinate system by doing:

```
Point relativeLocation = SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(location, parentComponent);
```

Finally, you can lookup a component at a location by doing:

```
Component myComponent = parentComponent.getComponentAt(relativeLocation);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Swing Explorer](https://swingexplorer.dev.java.net/). It allows you to explore the internals of your Swing app.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to discover this within the program itself, you can use a MouseListener and the sequence:

```
Event.getSource()
Object.getClass()
Class.getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to write a mouse listener doing such thing.